# problem with mysql export to file in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, export

i have a problem with mysql+c# in mysql export operation.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fol=new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (fol.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   string path= fol.SelectedPath;
   string sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '" + path+ "\person.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM tpers ";
   MySqlCommand daa = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
   conn.Open();
   daa.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();                              
}
```

for example
path = "c:\export"
but when i execute this code it doesnt export person.csv to intended path.
it creates "c:export\person.csv" file and creates this file in mysql/data folder..
can u explain the problem, and how to fix it...

Comment: Try `/export/person.csv`? Since this question has nothing to do with C# (or your application), you might want to ask on a MySql forum, specifically the provider of the Windows port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem..

```
string path = fol.SelectedPath;
path = path.Replace("\\","/");
...
```

after this my program works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me!! In my case needed to do in c#. Used with the `MySql.Data.dll v6.4.4`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/test.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE test_tmp CHARACTER SET UTF8  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5);
```